# Payex payment integration Final payment page Error

Tags: php

I have integrated Payex and final page returns an error as attached:

**/PayexExampleCode/MPFinalize.php**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [header] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Payex Header v1.0
                )

            [id] => 2dd334b571cb4e809a5d13c3bc7a51dd
            [date] => 2018-04-09 05:53:28
        )

    [status] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [code] => Access_MissingAccessProperties
            [errorCode] => Access_MissingAccessProperties
            [description] => Merchant does not have access to the method.
            [paramName] => SimpleXMLElement Object()

            [thirdPartyError] => SimpleXMLElement Object()

        )

)
```

Comment: you will need to read the documentation or ask the provider what that means

Comment: consult their documentation

Comment: No response from payex support since 5 days. Atleast someone who faced such error might be helpful.

Comment: _“Merchant does not have access to the method”_ pretty much sounds like the account configuration is missing something. You probably need to activate a specific payment flow, or they are waiting for confirmation of specific account details first, etc. pp.